# Unsupported Class File Major Version 8243

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm creating a survival games plugin and every time I run the plugin on my server, I get this error:

```
Fatal error trying to convert TerrorGames v1.0:me/TerrorGames/SurvivalGames/Main.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 8243
```

I had the JRE version at 1.8, but I changed it to Java 15 and nothing has changed. I have no errors in Eclipse, but this shows up every time I run the plugin. And the most confusing part about this is that `Java 8243` doesn't exist.

Comment: What command did you run exactly to generate `Main.class`? Can you upload it somewhere? I think it's corrupt.

Comment: I decided to just rewrite all the class files in a different project and it seems that it's fine now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the fix that I had for it was the following, either go to the class that is throwing the error, press a random letter on your keyboard to mark the file as edited, remove the random letter and save the file again. Either that or you can rebuild the entire project (Project -> Clean Build on the taskbar, or something along those lines)

Answer (score -1):

yeah, this error maddens me too, actually, you can't use any Java version above what your server uses, so if your server in running on Java 8 then you can't even use Java 9 to compile the plugin... its just like Standard, like kids can't understand higher syllabuses, same as that

Comment: There is no version of Java that uses class file version 8243. Unlike most times this error message occurs, this one isn't caused by a simple version mismatch.

Comment: also, you can absolutely write code for java 8 in a java 9 jdk, you just need to set the language level to jdk 8 so it doesn't try to use unsupported features.